# Determine the Longest Unidirectional Path in a Directed Disconnected Graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a directed disconnected graph in which some vertices (nodes) can be connected by multiple unidirectional relationships of different types. It is possible that the graph has loops.

How can I determine the length of the longest unidirectional path in my graph? I have been trying the following query with no success:

```
START n=node(*)
MATCH p=n<-[rels]-m 
WITH COLLECT(p) AS paths, MAX(length(p)) AS maxLength 
RETURN FILTER(path IN paths 
  WHERE length(path)= maxLength) AS longestPaths
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What's the problem with this query?  What does it produce and how does that differ from what you expect?

Comment: I would expect a figure (e. g. 10) staying for the path's length. My query delivers an extremely long output. Here is a sample:'code' [{"start":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/24","nodes":["http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/24","http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/21783"],"length":1,"relationships":["http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/3987"],"end":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/21783"},{"start":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/24","nodes":["http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/24","http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/21782"],"length":1,'code'

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
MATCH p=(n)<-[:RELTYPE*]-(m)
RETURN length(p)
ORDER BY LENGTH(p) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Be aware that this kind of query might be expensive depending the structure and size of your graph.

For Neo4j 1.9 use:

```
START n=node(*)
MATCH p=(n)<-[:RELTYPE*]-(m)
RETURN length(p)
ORDER BY LENGTH(p) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The query delivers an error message saying: "An unknown error occurred, was unable to retrieve a result for you." Should the query be working  with neo4j v. 1.9.5?

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help. The following query works perfectly: 'code'START n=node(*)
MATCH p=(n)<-[rels*]-(m)
RETURN length(p), n, m
ORDER BY LENGTH(p)DESC
LIMIT 10'code'